# Mail goes into spam box (included isnotspam log)

Tags: email, gmail, spam, spf, dkim

When i try to send mail from my server,it goes into spam box of gmail.I checked with Isnotspam website.Everything looks good expect DomainKeys Check.Can you verify my log and tell me how to solve this problem.

```
==========================================================
Summary of Results
==========================================================

SPF Check : pass
Sender-ID Check : pass
DomainKeys Check : neutral
DKIM Check : pass
SpamAssassin Check : ham (non-spam)
==========================================================
Details:
==========================================================

HELO hostname: mail.cybapps.com
Source IP: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
mail-from: mailme@cybapps.com
Anonymous To: ins-ywhteogz@isnotspam.com
---------------------------------------------------------
SPF check details:
----------------------------------------------------------

Result: pass
ID(s) verified: smtp.mail=mailme@cybapps.com
DNS record(s):
cybapps.com. 300 IN TXT "v=spf1 a mx ip4:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx ~all"


----------------------------------------------------------
Sender-ID check details:
----------------------------------------------------------

Result: pass

ID(s) verified: smtp.mail=mailme@cybapps.com
DNS record(s):
cybapps.com. 300 IN TXT "v=spf1 a mx ip4:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx ~all"


----------------------------------------------------------
DomainKeys check details:
----------------------------------------------------------

Result: neutral (message not signed)
ID(s) verified: header.From=mailme@cybapps.com
Selector=
domain=
DomainKeys DNS Record=

----------------------------------------------------------
DKIM check details:
----------------------------------------------------------

Result: pass
ID(s) verified: header.From=mailme@cybapps.com
Selector=mail
domain=cybapps.com
DomainKeys DNS Record=mail._domainkey.cybapps.com

----------------------------------------------------------
SpamAssassin check details:
----------------------------------------------------------
SpamAssassin 3.4.1 (2015-04-28)

Result: ham (non-spam) (03.6points, 10.0 required)

pts rule name description
---- ---------------------- -------------------------------


* 3.5 BAYES_99 BODY: Bayes spam probability is 99 to 100%
* [score: 1.0000]
* -0.0 T_RP_MATCHES_RCVD Envelope sender domain matches handover relay
* domain
* -0.0 SPF_PASS SPF: sender matches SPF record
* 0.2 BAYES_999 BODY: Bayes spam probability is 99.9 to 100%
* [score: 1.0000]
* -0.1 DKIM_VALID_AU Message has a valid DKIM or DK signature from author's
* domain
* -0.1 DKIM_VALID Message has at least one valid DKIM or DK signature
* 0.1 DKIM_SIGNED Message has a DKIM or DK signature, not necessarily
* valid
X-Spam-Status: Yes, hits=3.6 required=-20.0 tests=BAYES_99,BAYES_999,
DKIM_SIGNED,DKIM_VALID,DKIM_VALID_AU,SPF_PASS,T_RP_MATCHES_RCVD autolearn=no
autolearn_force=no version=3.4.1
X-Spam-Score: 3.6

To learn more about the terms used in the SpamAssassin report, please search
here: http://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/

==========================================================
Explanation of the possible results (adapted from
draft-kucherawy-sender-auth-header-04.txt):
==========================================================
```

Comment: Could it be the Bayes score that makes GMail believe it's spam? The Bayes  (or Bayesian) score is based on the word and word combinations in the mail. And it seems that IsNotSpam also detects the mail as Bayes spam (with a probability over 99%). So my guess is that it's the content that is detected as spam, and not the sending server.

Answer (score 0):

I did a DNS lookup to your domain and found it:

```
$ host -t txt cybapps.com
cybapps.com descriptive text "google-site-verification=r3eFsCxzevI8CjwQsDi21PbKILrMc-EQjfQsSe301Wk"
cybapps.com descriptive text "v=spf1 a mx ptr ip4:172.110.8.33 mx:cybapps.com ~all"
```

So, you're adding a Google verification TXT, which conflicts with SPF. Can you do Google verification via a file instead and try again? Note you'll need to wait until TTL expires.

Also note: a fail or neutral result on DKIM or DomainKey results does not turn your mail into SPAM. It's more likely that your MX server is/was on some blacklist. Also note your PTR record for given mail IP does not point to your mail server, but to your plain domain (it should be mail.cybapps.com instead):

```
$ host mail.cybapps.com
mail.cybapps.com has address 172.110.8.33
$ host 172.110.8.33
33.8.110.172.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer cybapps.com.
```

**EDIT:**

I usually use mxtoolbox to check my mail installation:
http://mxtoolbox.com/domain/cybapps.com/

Hope it helps!